# mysql Join table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I'm trying to join these tables:

```
            table1             table2             table3              
        -------------------------------------------------
             table1Id           table2Id           table3Id
               name              table1Id          table2Id
                                   name2             name3
```

How do I join these 3 tables?

for example something like this:
PS. Example is not working

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name2 , table3.name3 from table3 
left join  on(table2.table2Id=table3.table2Id)
left join  on(table1.table1Id=table2.table1Id) group by  table1.table1Id
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: İ dont understand error : #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no table specified after `left join`

Comment: @peace Is there a reason you are trying to use `group by`?  This is often used with analytical functions, which I don't see being used in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name must be specified after `left join`.  Also there is no need to use `group by` in this scenario.

```
SELECT table1.name, table2.name2 , table3.name3 
from table3 
left join table2 
on table3.table2Id = table2.table2Id
left join table1 
on table2.table1Id = table1.table1Id
```

Comment: @peace You need to specify the table after `left join` this is basic join syntax you could research.  The other problem was using `group by` with the query, which really didn't need to be used.